# Locating select element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is the combobox:

```
<TD ALIGN="left" id="oldcontent">
<select name="status" style="width=150" id="newcontentformat"><option value="14" selected="selected">text1</option>
<option value="15">text2</option>
<option value="16">text3</option></select>
</TD>
```

I need to select text2 in the combobox/dropdown.I have used the below:

```
selenium.select("//select[starts-with(@name,status)","text2");
```

The probelm am facing is,its giving me an error text2 not found.Since there are may other select boxes above this the same name status.So i need to select 2nd element of 2 dropdown/combobox.

Please provide me the solution.Its urgent.Thanks in Advance

Another td

```
<TD align="left" WIDTH="18%"><FONT ID="oldContent">
<select name="status" onchange="selectTime(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" id="newcontentformat">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">text100</option>
<option value="2">text200<</option>
<option value="3">text300<</option>
</TD>
```

Comment: can you post one more TD tag, so that I could post you the required answer ?

Comment: I hope that the below answer works fine as the id's of TD tag are different

Comment: Is it in an iFrame? Also try `//select[starts-with(@name,'status')`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work

```
selenium.select("//td[@id='oldcontent']/select","label=text2")
```

Comment: I have posted one more TD TAG ABOVE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with id of select tag.

```
selenium.select("//select[@id='newcontentformat']","label=text2");

                               or

selenium.select("//td[@id='oldContent']/select[@id='newcontentformat']","label=text2");
```

Answer (score 0):

well. I would try using css selectors solution:

```
String cssDropdown="select[id='newcontentformat']";
String csstext200="select[id='newcontentformat']>option[value='2']";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssDropdown)).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(csstext200)).click();
```

2nd aproach:
if jQuery is supported you can use following:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+csstext200+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.click()");
        (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Though this solution is not absolute but it wil work.
You can locate this dropdown by using : //select[@name='Status']/following::select[@name='Status']  YOU can add more following depending on the Number of dropdowns.  Also you can use preceding it ou want to start backwards.
 Please go through Selenium.1.0.Testing.Tools.Beginners.Guide Ebbok .

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://agra.quikr.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='alertcatSelectBox']")).sendKeys("Jobs");

// for your example
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='status']")).sendKeys("text2");