# Checkbox and dropdownbox in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is my code

Below is a  tag.

```
    <TR id="oldcontent" bgcolor="#D0D0D0">
    <TD id="ignore" style="vertical-align:middle">      
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedId" value="22047"onclick="updateSelectionList('<%=campaign.getId()%>')">
    </TD>
   <TD  id="oldcontent">Code</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="left" id="oldcontent">
    <select name="status" style="width=150" id="newcontentformat">
    <option value="14" selected="selected">text1</option>
    <option value="15">text2</option>
    </TD>
<TR>
```

Here
1)i need to click the checkbox which has dynamically generated value without any string.
2)Can i select the checkbox based on the text "Code" present in next  after checkbox?
3)I need to pick up text2 in the dropdown with name status
4)Lastly the issue is this  can appear any where in web page,everytime i run the test case.So i need to check the checkbox using String "code",2ndly i need to select value from dropdown which has name staus.There are other dropdown boxes with same name status.So how do i specifically do this?

Comment: You should try to only ask one question per question. Also, the dropdown question appears to be a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391647/locating-select-element-in-selenium)

Comment: Yes but this time i have to pick it up with respect to <tr> as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the select list in the row that has the text "Code", you can use the xpath:

```
//tr[./td[text()='Code']]/td/select
```

Similarly, for the checkbox, you can use the xpath:

```
//tr[./td[text()='Code']]/td/input[@type='checkbox']
```

I believe then the selenium code you want is:

```
selenium.select("//tr[./td[text()='Code']]/td/select", "text2")
selenium.check("//tr[./td[text()='Code']]/td/input[@type='checkbox']")
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are names available in the HTML, you can use Name to locate an element.

1. For click on check box you can write:

   ```
   selenium.click(//input[@name='selectedId']);
   ```
2. To go to check box using text locator should be like:

   ```
   //div[text()='text you want to precede']/preceding::input[@name='selectedId'];
   ```

   (here you can use any property instead of name.)
3. To pickup text from dropdowm:

   ```
   selenium.select(//select[@name='status'],"text2");
   ```

If you use such locators (which are position independent), no matter where your element appears on the screen, you can locate with the help of these locators....

To know more about locating preceding or following Download  Ebook:Selenium.1.0.Testing.Tools.Beginners.Guide